# Modified UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I have following control class withsome extra methods in it. I have multiple form usercontrols, FormChoosePage has dropdownlist with form list in it, and I get selected forms user control, load its data and after he click save button I call forms save method.

at btnSave_Click ucForm is null, I have 2 question;

1 ) how can I keep dynamicly Modified UserControl (View State or something?)

2 ) am I on right way to do this with generic user controls and everything. If not, what is you sugestion?

**FormControler**

```
public class Controler : UserControl
{
    public virtual void PageLoad() { }
    public virtual void SaveForm() { }
}
```

**Form UC**

```
    public partial class ApplicationForm : Controls.Controler
    {
        public override void PageLoad()
        {
            ddlFormType.DataSource = [Data];
            ddlFormType.DataBind();
        }

        public override void SaveForm()
        {
            XForm form = new XForm();
            form.something = txtSomething.Text; 
            form.Save();
        }
    }
```

**Form Choose Page**

```
    public partial class FormChoosePage: System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                ddlFormLoad();
            }
        }

        Controler ucForm;
        protected void ddlForm_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            XForm form = XForm.Get<XForm>(ddlForm.SelectedValue);

            ucForm = this.LoadControl(form.URL) as Controler;
            ucForm.ID = "ucForm";
            ucForm.PageLoad();
        }


        protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ucForm.SaveForm();
        }
   }
```

Comment: Why is it that your aren't declaring your DropdownList in the ascx file and dynamically loading it instead?  The control has to be loaded earlier in the page life cycle so that it will be present when the view state is set.  I believe Page_Init is what you are looking for.

Comment: I couldn't understand exactly what you mean but I used session to keep UC and seems working, but I am still interested if anyone has better solution or idea.